# PhpStorm deploys files though excluded paths

Tags: deployment, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I wanted to try the `Tools -> Deployment` in PhpStorm.

Thus I set up my web server under `Tools -> Deployment -> Configure` and added some "Excluded Paths". See attachment.

[image]

> I can't explain why PhpStorm still uploads these folders.

I hope someone has a helpful tip, thanks.

Comment: Paths are not absolute

Answer (score 3):

Remove those entries and add again using `Add local path` or `Add deployment path` buttons on the bottom of the screen.

Paths must be absolute (that's exactly what the warning on screenshot tells). Do not worry about that -- internally (in config files) they are stored relative to the project/content root and only displayed to you as full paths for your convenience.